# jplayer working in Visual Studio 2010 but not in browser

Tags: html, jplayer

I am using jplayer for audio in HTML5. The audio works when I am testing in Visual Studio 2010 and viewing in browser (from VS2010). However, if I am not in VS2010 and doubleclick on the .htm file to view in browser the audio is not working.  I am using IE9. Here is my code:

html5:

```
<script type="text/jscript" src="jQuery.jPlayer.2.2.0/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
   <!-- <script type="text/jscript" src="http://www.jplayer.org/2.2.0/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script> -->
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#jpId").jPlayer({
                ready: function () {
                    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                        mp3: "/HolidayCard/179_short_all-the-family-together_0033.MP3"
                    }).jPlayer("play");
                },
                //swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/Jplayer.swf",
                swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/2.2.0/js",
                solution: "html,flash",
                supplied: "mp3",
                wmode: "window"


            });

        });
```

HTML5 div tag:

```
<div id="jpId" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely caused by not having an absolute path to your file. If you view this in visual studio, it most likely knows the relative path to your file and that's why you can view it through VS. Try adding the full path to your .htm file and see if that helps. You can also use Chrome Dev Tools, Firebug or IE Dev Tools to see what error your .htm file is throwing to help you solve the problem. Generally as a rule of thumb, the majority of your testing should be done through a browser as opposed to the VS browser. Also, if this is a web page that is for a live website, I would suggest testing it in the 3 major browsers too (IE, Chrome and Firefox) to be sure of cross browser compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have tested in IE8, Chrome, and I know I will need  a .ogg file for Firefox. Are you referring to the asolute path for the jplayer? I have tried the code below and it still only works in VS2010.

    <script type="text/jscript" src="http://www.jplayer.org/2.2.0/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>

All other jquery is working correctly. I am just having issues with the jplayer. Thank you.

Comment: I assumed you were referring to the mp3 file not playing. For the jplayer. Did you check to see if there were any errors being thrown in Dev Tools?

Comment: I changed the path of the audio file to a relative path and it now works outside of VS2010 on another directory.The problem I am running into now is that when I put the .html file on the web server the audio is not working.

Comment: Can you confirm that the there aren't any permission issues when accessing the audio file? If that's not the case, make sure that the path to the audio file from the server is correct. Another thing to check is that .mp3 is an available MIME type in IIS, if it's not you will need to add it.

Comment: Thanks fo rall your help. The issue was due to the path to the audio file on the web server.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it figured out. These small issues can be the most frustrating.